# Transform image into other

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Using PIL and tkinter, I'm trying to do some manipulations in the pixelMatrix of an image like:

```
start = Image.open("gua.jpg")
sta  = start.load()
i,j = start.size
current = np.zeros((i,j,3))

for ix in range(i):
    for jx in range(j):
         current[ix,jx] = [elem*0.5 for elem in sta[ix,jx]]

current = np.asarray(current)
current = Image.fromarray(current, "RGB")
out = ImageTk.PhotoImage(current)

panel.configure(image = out)
panel.image = out
```

But even if i just pass the info from the image's pixelMatrix to my matrix(`current[ix,jx] = sta[ix,jx]`), my result is random, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

[image]

P.S:I can do `out = ImageTk.PhotoImage(start)` without problems.

Comment: After you do `current = np.asarray(current)` what does `current` actually look like? (print it out and post the first bit, I know it is going to be really big)

Comment: when inside the loop, I do `print sta[ix,jx], current[ix,jx]` that's the output:

`(128, 128, 120) [ 128.  128.  120.]`

after casting it to array that's what i get: 
`...  [[ 179.  179.  177.]
  [ 174.  174.  172.]
  [ 167.  167.  165.]
  ..., 
  [  73.   68.   64.]
  [  84.   70.   67.]
  [ 153.  133.  132.]]
...`

Comment: what do you expect? I mean what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that the `dtype` of your array is `np.uint8`:

```
current = np.zeros((i,j,3),dtype=np.uint8)
```

If you do not specify this when PIL uses the `.tobytes()` method on the array it gets data that does not make sense for `"RGB"` because it is for floating point numbers.

Also note that `fromarray` takes data row by row so the height will need to be the first dimension of the array, you can fix this by simply taking the `transpose` before passing it to `fromarray`:

```
img = Image.fromarray(current.transpose(1,0,2))
```